# Why one of the package s I've installed is unaccessible in Guake Terminal?

Tags: package-management, gnome-terminal, guake

I installed Rails framework (Ruby on Rails) on my Ubuntu.
Today after I installed Guake Terminal, and I called Rails command in it =>

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed
```

Rails still works in Ubuntu Terminal but Why it is unaccessible from Guake Terminal ?

(But other packages like Cowsay! I've installed before are accessible in Guake)

Comment: Did you try closing out guake entirely, then reopening it?  Maybe the running console session hasn't detected `rails` as being installed, or maybe you're SSH'd to some other system and it's not installed there?